# ASP.NET MVC return 3 actions in one view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a small problem, I'm trying to display Facebook, Instagram and twitter in one view and order them by date, but i'm not really sure how can i achieve that

Here is my ActionResult for Twitter, then I have almost identical for Instagram and Facebook

```
        var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(auth);
        ulong sinceId = 1;
        const int Count = 20;

        var combinedSearchResults = new List<Status>();
        var tweets =
            await
            (from tweet in twitterContext.Status
             where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
             tweet.Count == Count &&
             tweet.RetweetedStatus.StatusID == 0 &&
             tweet.ExcludeReplies == true &&

             tweet.SinceID == sinceId

             select new NewsViewModel
             {
                 DateAdded = tweet.CreatedAt,
                 ScreenName = tweet.User.ScreenNameResponse,
                 Text = tweet.Text,
                 StatusId = tweet.StatusID
             })
            .ToListAsync();
        return View(tweets);

    }
```

how can I put all those 3 together and display them in Index view ?
I'm kinda new to this stuff, would really appreciate the answer and help

Comment: You need to have partial view for each social media. This might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take all three sources and display them together in a single list.

Assuming you can convert all three to your `NewsViewModel` type, then just add the results from Facebook and Instagram to the same list, and just pass that one list to your view.

So you don't use three views - you get data from the three data sources in your controller, then pass the consolidated list to the one view.

Something like this (consolidated, but you get the idea):

```
var posts = await (from tweet ...).ToListAsync(); //what you already have
posts.AddRange(await (from facebook ....).ToListAsync());
posts.AddRange(await (from instagram ....).ToListAsync());
return View(posts);
```

Answer (score 1):

### ASP.NET Core

It can be achived by creating three components direved from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent`:

```
public class TwitterViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string parameter)
    {
        ...
        return View(tweets);
    }
}
```

then create common view `Views\Shared\Components\Twitter\Default.cshtml` or specific for controller view `Views\[controllerName]\Components\Twitter\Default.cshtml` depending on your needs.

And then you can render your component like this:

```
<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Twitter", new { parameter = "parameterValue"})
</div>
```

### ASP.NET MVC 5 and earlier

You can just render child action in your view:

```
<div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Twitter");}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this:

```
var postList = new PostList();
var twitterPost = await GetTwitterpost(....);
var fbPost = await GetFbPost(....);
var instagramPost = await GetInstagramPost(....);
if(twitterPost !=null)
  postList.AddRange(twitterPost);
if(fbPost !=null)
  postList.AddRange(fbPost);
if(instagramPost !=null)
  postList.AddRange(instagramPost);

postList = postList?.OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateAdded).ToList();

return View(postList);
```

I don't know if i really understand what you want ! But this way you get all your post in one collection and you can display them by date.